# Como omitir parâmetros na passagem de parâmetro real?

Tags: c++, funções, parâmetros

Tenho uma função em C++ chamada `minhaFuncao()` declarada assim:

```
minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a);
```

e implementada assim:

```
minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a=0){
...
}
```

O que estou querendo dizer é, quando for chamar a `minhaFuncao` e passar os parâmetros reais para ela, queria poder omitir alguns parâmetros, ou seja, se eu não passar o parâmetro real, o parâmetro formal recebe o valor que já lhe foi atribuído como em `float a=0`, penso em algo dessa maneira:

```
minhaFuncao(1, 1);
```

percebam que não passei o parâmetro real que iria ser atribuído a `float a`, então o que queria é que ele por não ser passado recebesse o "0" ou qualquer outro valor padrão escrito anteriormente na implementação da função. Mas caso eu decida passar, que ele receba normalmente, como abaixo:

```
minhaFUncao(1, 1, 1.5);
```

percebam agora que passei o parâmetro real "1.5" para `float a`, precisava que ele valesse "1.5" agora em vez do "0" colocado como padrão.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso em C++, lembro que já li isso, mas não estou achando de jeito nenhum, não sei que palavras usar para pesquisar.

Uma coisa percebi, é que se existe uma maneira de fazer isso, terá suas limitações, como a função implementada abaixo não seria possível:

```
minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a=0, int b, int c=0){
...
}
```

Acho que uma das regras para isso seria que apenas poderiam ser omitidos os parâmetros finais, assim:

```
minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a, int b=0, int c=0){
...
}
```

porque na hora de chamar a `minhaFuncao()`, na primeira forma, daria errado, não saberia o que está sendo omitido ou não, então por isso teria que ter essa regra, ou um jeito de especificar todos parâmetros na hora de passar os reais assim:

```
minhaFuncao(x=1, y=1, b=1, c=1);
```

aqui omiti o parâmetro `float a`. Qual a maneira certa de fazer isso em c++ se for possível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única coisa que está errada na sua tentativa é que o valor *default* precisa estar na declaração e não na implementação. Assim:

```
minhaFuncao(int, int, float = 0); //declaração

minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a) {} //definição/implementação
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/DefaultArgument2.cpp).

O compilador do C++ colocará por você a atribuição do valor antes de fazer a chamada da função. Isso é o mais puro açúcar sintático.

Não pode pular um e colocar outro, quando tiver um parâmetro opcional, todos os seguintes devem ser opcionais.

Comment: Então na declaração coloco assim: `minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a = 0);` e na implementação assim: `minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a);` ? E a segunda parte da questão, está correto? posso especificar os parâmetros na chamada da função?

Comment: Sim, tudo correto.

Comment: Valeu, que bom que tem como fazer isso, estava mesmo precisando, vai me poupar algumas linhas.

Comment: Testei aqui agora, não dá certo a parte de especificar, recebo um erro se fizer isso: `minhaFuncao(x=1, y=1, b=1, c=1);`, como faria em caso que tivesse assim na declaração `minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a = 0, int b=0, int c=0);` e quisesse omitir o parâmetro "int b" apenas?

Comment: Isto não é possível, conforme está na sua pergunta.

Comment: Lá está uma suposição que poderia fazer dessa maneira, achei que até a suposição estava valendo kkkkk Seria bom, mas já dando para omitir os parâmetros em ordem, já ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

O valor *default* de um parâmetro deve aparecer na declaração da função, já que a declaração é a única coisa que o chamador enxerga.

Por exemplo, se você colocar a declaração em um arquivo de cabeçalho, e a definição em um arquivo `.cpp` separado, e `#include` (incluir) o cabeçalho de um arquivo `.cpp` diferente, você poderá ver com mais facilidade a diferença.

Considere:

#### minhalib.h

```
void minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a);
```

#### minhalib.cpp

```
void minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a = 0) {
   ...
}
```

#### teste.cpp

```
#include "minhalib.h"

int main() {
    minhaFuncao(1, 2);
}
```

A compilação de `teste.cpp` não vai enxergar a declaração do parâmetro *default*, falhando com um erro.

Por esta razão, a definição do parâmetro *default* é usualmente especificado na declaração da função.

#### minhalib.h

```
void minhaFuncao(int x, int y, float a = 0);
```

Comment: Agradeço pela explicação, estava nessa situação mesmo, arquivos separados.